# SSH command to find and delete all files that contain a string

Tags: unix, ssh, grep, find

I need to use SSH to find all files containing a certain string (malware) and delete these files.

This is the command I am using to find and display a list of these malware files:

```
find * -name '*.php' -exec grep -l "return base64_decode(" {} \;
```

and I get a list like this:

[image]

I want to delete all these files (not just display a list of them).

Basically "find all files that contain a string, and delete those files".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say pipe `xargs rm` so that the given file names will be removed:

```
find * -name '*.php' -exec grep -l "return base64_decode(" {} \; | xargs rm
```

You can also store the current output of `find` and then loop through the content executing `rm <file>`:

```
find ... > file
while IFS= read -r file
do
    rm "$file"
done < file
```

Comment: Glad to read this, @AlboBest : ) Out of curiosity: which version did you use, the `find | xargs rm` or the one with the loop?

Comment: I used `find | xargs rm`
I have no idea how to use the other version/code, lol :)

Comment: @AlboBest ok maybe it wasn't very well explained. The thing here is to say `find ...` and output to a file. Then, loop through the file with the `while` loop.